# Excel: How do I list all the values in that column based on dynamic column header name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

This is my scenario, The "Creative Direction" Sheet is a template that I give to my clients. When it is returned to me, they've added extra columns in between of my columns. It takes a long time to clean when it is full of data.

I wanted to create a another sheet where it will arrange the original columns without the extra columns. And list down all the cell values below that column.

My thought process was I need to lookup the column names from "Sheet4" from "Creative Media Plan". So wherever that column name is located in the "Creative Media Plan" sheet. It will be found then it will list all the cell values from that column in "Sheet4". I hope this made sense.

This is the new link. You can download as Excel File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xTQ0Unewvn-iq-OuP-62jyCkP-xsbZORMA4cQxdLW48/edit?usp=sharing

Below is my sample workbook

[image: Main sheet]

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? If not the latest one (office 365), van you upgrade to it?

Comment: I have the office 365. Enterprise account though

Comment: Welcome! Your question is missing a screenshot of the Validation sheet in the area of cell K1

Comment: Let me share the file. You can download the workbook here.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AXyBcdQL_GwgtCS9M5aQQKAfZDBKIyUKuyvOihWZJbg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, but the problem is still not clear. You can fill the fifth row without much difficulty with the usual `=COLUMN()` - neither `MATCH()` nor `XMATCH()` is needed for this. The sixth row can be filled in simply by typing `='Creative Direction | Media Plan'!A6` (or `=Validation!K1`) and stretching this formula to the right.

Comment: Apologies but there just isn't nearly enough information here to understand what you are trying to do.  it is extremely helpful to provide an example of what you want to have happen.  By that, I mean, create a Tab "Sheet 4" and manually type into it what you want the automated output to look like given a certain lookup.  Also, based on my limited understanding of the problem, what you are trying to do is a use case for the FILTER function and not HLOOKUP.  HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP return a value, filter returns a column or row.

Comment: I'm sorry to everyone who tried and I realized didn't clearly the problem and expected solution. I will edit my original post

Comment: You should be able to do this with `XLOOKUP()`

Answer (score 0):

With Excel O365 this is very straightforward.

Let's make the following assumptions just to make sure there's no ambiguity in the formula below:

1. The column headers in the customer-provided sheet are in row 6, starting at A6.  Therefore the useful data I want to retrieve starts in row 7 of each column.
2. The column headers in your results sheet (Sheet4) are also in row 6, and also start at A6.
3. For this illustration lets assume there are 100 rows of data, in rows 7 through 106.
4. To keep it simple, let's also assume that the customer added a "few" columns, but not "many" columns, so we're going to contain our lookup to say, 52 columns, A through AZ.

In A7 of the *destination* sheet (Sheet4), you would enter this formula, just below the column header name in A6:

`=FILTER('Creative Direction | Media Plan'!$A7:$AZ106),'Creative Direction | Media Plan'!$A6:$AZ6=A7,"Col Missing")`

This says "If there is a column title in 'Creative Direction | Media Plan' that matches the column title in local sheet A7, just give me the whole column.  If no column is found, it means the customer either deleted the column, or they edited the name intentionally or accidentally, so just list the column as being missing."

Then copy it across your 17 columns.  Since you are copying across to the right, it is important that the ranges on the customer-provided sheets are locked to be $A through $AZ, and important that the local A7 reference is *not* locked.

This is the beauty of O365's dynamic arrays, functions like FILTER are literal game changers.